# Referenced dlls are not included in nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I have created a Class Library(Package) project called 'AMS'. Then i have added reference of a dll called 'infrastructure from another solution on my local machine. Now, when i build AMS project, it creates a nuget package for me. 
Now, when i add this package using my local nuget repository to a new web application, it throws below error.

"NU1001 The dependency Infrastructure >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved."

All three applications are using same dotnet version 4.6. Isn't it possible to add dlls in a package, if yes, where am i doing wrong.

Comment: Could you post the nuspec file you are using to create the package?

Comment: @Kazuo: I am not using any nuspec file. VS 2015 creates package on its own if you use class library(package) template & enable "Produce on output builds" in Build section.

Answer (score -1):

The class library package only puts the output dll into the nuget package. Best practice is to make another nuget package from your infrastructure DLL and add a nuget dependency on it. It's important that NuGet have visibility into the dependency graph at a package level so that it can do a better job at rationalizing the versions.

Comment: I read this solution somewhere, but in our case, there are a lot of dlls in which case, it is not feasible to convert all dlls into packages. I do understand the need of dependency graph, but there must be some way to include dlls(if corresponding package is not there) as content in lib folder. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: Lets say you have different packages that all internalize different versions of the infrastructure DLL, which version of that infrastructure DLL should win? Highest? Lowest? Which one ends up in the bin folder? Those are the sorts of problems you run into when NuGet doesn't have visibility into the dependency graph.